# Dojo: how to emit 'change' properly on custom widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

So, imagine there is a listener for native `dijit/form/Select` element, which listens for `change` event:

```
nativeSelectWidget.on('change', lang.hitch(this, onSelectClick));
```

Now, I have created my own custom widget similar to Select and trying to listen using the same code:

```
mySelectWidget.on('change', lang.hitch(this, onSelectClick));
```

The `onSelectClick` looks like:

```
_onTypeChange: function(value) {
  console.debug('The value is, value)
}
```

The problem is that in the second case `onSelectClick` doesn't receive any values (`undefined`).

Tried to add:

```
on.emit(this.domNode, 'change', {
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
});
```

to widget's `_setValueAttr`, tried to remove it. No value has been passed.. checked how native `Select` is defined - https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/form/Select.js

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the way you want to use it, you should do (in your custom widget):

1) inherits from `dojo/Evented`
2) add the following:

```
_setValueAttr: function(value) {
    this._set('value', value);
    this.emit('change', value);
}
```

That should do the trick

However, this implementation has a drawback:
If you change the value from another piece of code, the emit will still be send, and usually we want the emit ONLY for user events, not for programmatic changes.